# Websites with different information have same URL - how to extract all information?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to use beautiful soup to extract the values in the points column in the table on this website: [link](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics). But the table only displays 30 players per page, after which you have to click the arrow at the bottom to view the next batch of players. This doesn't seem to change the actual url which is input in beautiful soup. Upon using inspect element it is clear that while page 1 in displayed, the site doesn't contain any information about pages 2, 3, etc.

So how can I extract the information from all the pages when they all seem to have the same url, but don't all contain the information of all the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selenium` to continue clicking the "forward" button until it is disabled:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics')
results = []
def player(p):
   return {'img':p.img['src'], 'name':p.find('div', {'class':'ElementInTable__Name-y9xi40-1 bsSrWV'}).text, **dict(zip(['team', 'pos'], [i.text for i in p.find_all('span')]))}

def page_data(page):
   t = page.find('table', {'class':'Table-ziussd-1 ElementTable-sc-1v08od9-0 jXIUKt'})
   h, _d = [i.text for i in t.find('tr').find_all('th')][1:], [(lambda x:[player(x[0]), *[k.text for k in x[1:]]])(i.find_all('td')[1:]) for i in t.find_all('tr')[1:]]
   return [dict(zip(h, i)) for i in _d]

flag = False 
while len((x:=soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')).find_all('button', {'class':'PaginatorButton__Button-xqlaki-0 lgWpws'})) == 2 or not flag:
  results.append(page_data(x))
  b = [i for i in d.find_elements_by_tag_name('button') if i.get_attribute('class') == 'PaginatorButton__Button-xqlaki-0 lgWpws']
  b[-1].send_keys('\n')
  flag = True

results.append(page_data(x))
```

Output (first four pages):

```
[[{'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Vardy', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '10.1', 'Sel.': '51.5%', 'Form': '5.7', 'Pts.': '144'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'De Bruyne', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '10.5', 'Sel.': '49.7%', 'Form': '8.0', 'Pts.': '139'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Mané', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '12.3', 'Sel.': '38.2%', 'Form': '6.7', 'Pts.': '132'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_3-66.png', 'name': 'Aubameyang', 'team': 'ARS', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '10.8', 'Sel.': '17.8%', 'Form': '6.7', 'Pts.': '121'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_1-66.png', 'name': 'Rashford', 'team': 'MUN', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '9.1', 'Sel.': '28.7%', 'Form': '6.6', 'Pts.': '120'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_8-66.png', 'name': 'Abraham', 'team': 'CHE', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '7.8', 'Sel.': '32.5%', 'Form': '3.9', 'Pts.': '110'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Salah', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '12.3', 'Sel.': '24.4%', 'Form': '6.3', 'Pts.': '110'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Sterling', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '11.8', 'Sel.': '23.9%', 'Form': '5.7', 'Pts.': '109'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_20-66.png', 'name': 'Ings', 'team': 'SOU', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.6', 'Sel.': '16.7%', 'Form': '7.3', 'Pts.': '109'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Alexander-Arnold', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '7.4', 'Sel.': '35.3%', 'Form': '8.7', 'Pts.': '106'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Jiménez', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '7.5', 'Sel.': '17.8%', 'Form': '5.1', 'Pts.': '104'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_6-66.png', 'name': 'Kane', 'team': 'TOT', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '11.0', 'Sel.': '20.7%', 'Form': '5.6', 'Pts.': '102'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_45-66.png', 'name': 'Pukki', 'team': 'NOR', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.5', 'Sel.': '16.0%', 'Form': '4.6', 'Pts.': '98'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Lundstram', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.2', 'Sel.': '48.5%', 'Form': '3.4', 'Pts.': '97'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Maddison', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.7', 'Sel.': '25.8%', 'Form': '3.9', 'Pts.': '92'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_11-66.png', 'name': 'Richarlison', 'team': 'EVE', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '8.0', 'Sel.': '10.3%', 'Form': '4.7', 'Pts.': '91'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Baldock', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '10.8%', 'Form': '5.4', 'Pts.': '90'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Firmino', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '9.2', 'Sel.': '8.8%', 'Form': '4.0', 'Pts.': '89'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_6-66.png', 'name': 'Son', 'team': 'TOT', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '9.8', 'Sel.': '6.0%', 'Form': '3.6', 'Pts.': '89'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Pereira', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '6.4', 'Sel.': '15.4%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '86'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Robertson', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '7.0', 'Sel.': '18.8%', 'Form': '3.8', 'Pts.': '86'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'van Dijk', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '6.4', 'Sel.': '39.7%', 'Form': '7.2', 'Pts.': '85'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_8-66.png', 'name': 'Willian', 'team': 'CHE', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.1', 'Sel.': '5.4%', 'Form': '4.7', 'Pts.': '84'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Mahrez', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '8.3', 'Sel.': '4.7%', 'Form': '4.0', 'Pts.': '84'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Agüero', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '11.7', 'Sel.': '10.6%', 'Form': '1.4', 'Pts.': '82'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_7-66.png', 'name': 'Grealish', 'team': 'AVL', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.4', 'Sel.': '16.9%', 'Form': '4.6', 'Pts.': '81'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Traoré', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.5', 'Sel.': '12.9%', 'Form': '4.7', 'Pts.': '81'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Evans', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.2', 'Sel.': '6.4%', 'Form': '3.9', 'Pts.': '80'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_8-66.png', 'name': 'Mount', 'team': 'CHE', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.4', 'Sel.': '21.1%', 'Form': '2.9', 'Pts.': '79'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'David Silva', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.4', 'Sel.': '4.5%', 'Form': '2.3', 'Pts.': '79'}], [{'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_1-66.png', 'name': 'Martial', 'team': 'MUN', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.9', 'Sel.': '11.9%', 'Form': '5.6', 'Pts.': '79'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49_1-66.png', 'name': 'Henderson', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '9.3%', 'Form': '4.0', 'Pts.': '79'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_57_1-66.png', 'name': 'Foster', 'team': 'WAT', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.8', 'Sel.': '2.6%', 'Form': '4.6', 'Pts.': '79'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_36_1-66.png', 'name': 'Ryan', 'team': 'BHA', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.8', 'Sel.': '17.0%', 'Form': '2.9', 'Pts.': '78'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_36-66.png', 'name': 'Maupay', 'team': 'BHA', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '5.8', 'Sel.': '2.2%', 'Form': '4.6', 'Pts.': '78'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13_1-66.png', 'name': 'Schmeichel', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '15.0%', 'Form': '2.9', 'Pts.': '78'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91_1-66.png', 'name': 'Ramsdale', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.7', 'Sel.': '6.1%', 'Form': '3.1', 'Pts.': '76'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31_1-66.png', 'name': 'Guaita', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '3.5%', 'Form': '5.9', 'Pts.': '76'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_4_1-66.png', 'name': 'Dubravka', 'team': 'NEW', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '1.3%', 'Form': '4.7', 'Pts.': '76'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Stevens', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '2.4%', 'Form': '3.4', 'Pts.': '76'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39_1-66.png', 'name': 'Patrício', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.2', 'Sel.': '10.6%', 'Form': '3.6', 'Pts.': '76'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_45-66.png', 'name': 'Cantwell', 'team': 'NOR', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '4.8', 'Sel.': '22.5%', 'Form': '3.6', 'Pts.': '74'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90_1-66.png', 'name': 'Pope', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.7', 'Sel.': '14.2%', 'Form': '2.7', 'Pts.': '73'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Söyüncü', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '19.2%', 'Form': '1.7', 'Pts.': '73'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Tielemans', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.4', 'Sel.': '6.2%', 'Form': '1.9', 'Pts.': '73'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_6-66.png', 'name': 'Alli', 'team': 'TOT', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '8.9', 'Sel.': '15.0%', 'Form': '6.6', 'Pts.': '73'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90-66.png', 'name': 'Tarkowski', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '4.4%', 'Form': '2.3', 'Pts.': '72'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'Ayew', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '7.3%', 'Form': '3.4', 'Pts.': '72'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Bernardo Silva', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.9', 'Sel.': '9.2%', 'Form': '2.3', 'Pts.': '72'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Doherty', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '6.1', 'Sel.': '4.6%', 'Form': '4.3', 'Pts.': '72'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_1-66.png', 'name': 'James', 'team': 'MUN', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.1', 'Sel.': '10.0%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '71'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_36-66.png', 'name': 'Dunk', 'team': 'BHA', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.7', 'Sel.': '12.7%', 'Form': '3.1', 'Pts.': '70'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Pérez', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.0', 'Sel.': '4.4%', 'Form': '2.3', 'Pts.': '70'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Chilwell', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.7', 'Sel.': '11.3%', 'Form': '1.0', 'Pts.': '69'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_20-66.png', 'name': 'Ward-Prowse', 'team': 'SOU', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.9', 'Sel.': '2.1%', 'Form': '3.6', 'Pts.': '69'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90-66.png', 'name': 'Wood', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.2', 'Sel.': '0.9%', 'Form': '2.9', 'Pts.': '68'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_11-66.png', 'name': 'Calvert-Lewin', 'team': 'EVE', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '5.8', 'Sel.': '3.2%', 'Form': '5.4', 'Pts.': '68'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': "O'Connell", 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.6', 'Sel.': '2.2%', 'Form': '2.9', 'Pts.': '68'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_8-66.png', 'name': 'Pulisic', 'team': 'CHE', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.1', 'Sel.': '6.7%', 'Form': '1.4', 'Pts.': '67'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Moutinho', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '5.5%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '67'}], [{'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_3_1-66.png', 'name': 'Leno', 'team': 'ARS', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '5.2%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '66'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'Zaha', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.9', 'Sel.': '12.2%', 'Form': '4.3', 'Pts.': '66'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_21-66.png', 'name': 'Haller', 'team': 'WHU', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '7.0', 'Sel.': '2.3%', 'Form': '2.7', 'Pts.': '66'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91-66.png', 'name': 'Callum Wilson', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '7.4', 'Sel.': '4.8%', 'Form': '1.3', 'Pts.': '65'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90-66.png', 'name': 'McNeil', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.0', 'Sel.': '0.6%', 'Form': '1.9', 'Pts.': '65'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_11_1-66.png', 'name': 'Pickford', 'team': 'EVE', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.3', 'Sel.': '7.1%', 'Form': '3.6', 'Pts.': '64'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Egan', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.5', 'Sel.': '0.8%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '63'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Fleck', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '2.3%', 'Form': '3.4', 'Pts.': '63'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91-66.png', 'name': 'Harry Wilson', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.9', 'Sel.': '2.3%', 'Form': '2.4', 'Pts.': '62'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_1_1-66.png', 'name': 'de Gea', 'team': 'MUN', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '12.4%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '62'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Mousset', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '3.9%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '62'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_7-66.png', 'name': 'El Ghazi', 'team': 'AVL', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.5', 'Sel.': '1.2%', 'Form': '1.9', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_7-66.png', 'name': 'McGinn', 'team': 'AVL', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.6', 'Sel.': '4.4%', 'Form': '1.1', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_7-66.png', 'name': 'Wesley', 'team': 'AVL', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '5.6', 'Sel.': '1.5%', 'Form': '1.7', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Jesus', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '9.5', 'Sel.': '2.1%', 'Form': '4.1', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_4-66.png', 'name': 'Willems', 'team': 'NEW', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.7', 'Sel.': '3.0%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_45-66.png', 'name': 'Buendía', 'team': 'NOR', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.0', 'Sel.': '0.8%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Basham', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.5', 'Sel.': '0.7%', 'Form': '2.7', 'Pts.': '61'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90-66.png', 'name': 'Barnes', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.2', 'Sel.': '2.9%', 'Form': '1.3', 'Pts.': '60'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Barnes', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.9', 'Sel.': '0.7%', 'Form': '2.0', 'Pts.': '60'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_4-66.png', 'name': 'Shelvey', 'team': 'NEW', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '1.9%', 'Form': '4.6', 'Pts.': '60'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_11-66.png', 'name': 'Digne', 'team': 'EVE', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.7', 'Sel.': '11.9%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '59'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91-66.png', 'name': 'King', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.1', 'Sel.': '3.9%', 'Form': '1.1', 'Pts.': '58'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'Kelly', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.4', 'Sel.': '32.5%', 'Form': '4.0', 'Pts.': '58'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_7_1-66.png', 'name': 'Heaton', 'team': 'AVL', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.5', 'Sel.': '5.4%', 'Form': '2.7', 'Pts.': '57'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_36-66.png', 'name': 'Groß', 'team': 'BHA', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.4', 'Sel.': '0.6%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '57'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43_1-66.png', 'name': 'Ederson', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '6.0', 'Sel.': '12.4%', 'Form': '1.4', 'Pts.': '57'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_57-66.png', 'name': 'Deulofeu', 'team': 'WAT', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.1', 'Sel.': '2.2%', 'Form': '2.4', 'Pts.': '57'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'Milivojevic', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.7', 'Sel.': '2.3%', 'Form': '2.7', 'Pts.': '56'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_13-66.png', 'name': 'Ndidi', 'team': 'LEI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '2.6%', 'Form': '2.0', 'Pts.': '56'}], [{'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_45_1-66.png', 'name': 'Krul', 'team': 'NOR', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '4.5', 'Sel.': '2.1%', 'Form': '1.1', 'Pts.': '56'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'van Aanholt', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.5', 'Sel.': '5.5%', 'Form': '1.6', 'Pts.': '55'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_1-66.png', 'name': 'McTominay', 'team': 'MUN', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '1.8%', 'Form': '1.1', 'Pts.': '55'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_49-66.png', 'name': 'Norwood', 'team': 'SHU', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '0.3%', 'Form': '3.3', 'Pts.': '55'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90-66.png', 'name': 'Westwood', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '0.4%', 'Form': '2.4', 'Pts.': '54'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Henderson', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '1.0%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '54'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_14-66.png', 'name': 'Wijnaldum', 'team': 'LIV', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '2.3%', 'Form': '2.8', 'Pts.': '54'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Walker', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.8', 'Sel.': '11.7%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '54'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_6-66.png', 'name': 'Aurier', 'team': 'TOT', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.1', 'Sel.': '8.3%', 'Form': '2.7', 'Pts.': '54'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_6-66.png', 'name': 'Lucas Moura', 'team': 'TOT', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.2', 'Sel.': '6.0%', 'Form': '3.6', 'Pts.': '54'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'McArthur', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.2', 'Sel.': '0.7%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '53'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Neves', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.3', 'Sel.': '4.9%', 'Form': '2.4', 'Pts.': '53'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91-66.png', 'name': 'Rico', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.4', 'Sel.': '14.4%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '52'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_90-66.png', 'name': 'Mee', 'team': 'BUR', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '0.9%', 'Form': '2.1', 'Pts.': '52'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_8-66.png', 'name': 'Jorginho', 'team': 'CHE', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '3.2%', 'Form': '1.9', 'Pts.': '52'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_4-66.png', 'name': 'Almirón', 'team': 'NEW', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.8', 'Sel.': '0.5%', 'Form': '3.4', 'Pts.': '52'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Jota', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '6.1', 'Sel.': '3.2%', 'Form': '3.4', 'Pts.': '52'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91-66.png', 'name': 'Fraser', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '6.9', 'Sel.': '2.9%', 'Form': '1.9', 'Pts.': '51'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_8_1-66.png', 'name': 'Kepa', 'team': 'CHE', 'pos': 'GKP'}, 'Cost': '5.5', 'Sel.': '5.2%', 'Form': '2.6', 'Pts.': '51'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_57-66.png', 'name': 'Cathcart', 'team': 'WAT', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.3', 'Sel.': '1.6%', 'Form': '3.1', 'Pts.': '51'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_21-66.png', 'name': 'Ogbonna', 'team': 'WHU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.5', 'Sel.': '1.3%', 'Form': '3.5', 'Pts.': '51'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_3-66.png', 'name': 'Lacazette', 'team': 'ARS', 'pos': 'FWD'}, 'Cost': '9.3', 'Sel.': '1.6%', 'Form': '1.7', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_91-66.png', 'name': 'Aké', 'team': 'BOU', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '7.1%', 'Form': '0.6', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_36-66.png', 'name': 'Trossard', 'team': 'BHA', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.8', 'Sel.': '0.3%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_31-66.png', 'name': 'Kouyaté', 'team': 'CRY', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '4.9', 'Sel.': '0.3%', 'Form': '3.3', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_11-66.png', 'name': 'Sigurdsson', 'team': 'EVE', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '7.3', 'Sel.': '2.6%', 'Form': '2.4', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_43-66.png', 'name': 'Rodrigo', 'team': 'MCI', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '5.4', 'Sel.': '1.1%', 'Form': '2.9', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_1-66.png', 'name': 'Lindelöf', 'team': 'MUN', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.3', 'Sel.': '1.3%', 'Form': '3.0', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_39-66.png', 'name': 'Coady', 'team': 'WOL', 'pos': 'DEF'}, 'Cost': '5.0', 'Sel.': '1.5%', 'Form': '2.3', 'Pts.': '50'}, {'Player': {'img': '/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_3-66.png', 'name': 'Pépé', 'team': 'ARS', 'pos': 'MID'}, 'Cost': '9.1', 'Sel.': '2.2%', 'Form': '2.4', 'Pts.': '49'}]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like an on-click event, something you cannot directly take out of the HTML code with BS. However, it is possible to scrape this with Selenium.